# Not able to clear `npm` cache throws error `Cannot find module 'pump'`

Tags: node.js, npm

In my windows system I am trying to clear the `npm cache`, But getting error as :

```
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module 'pump'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MB112830\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-03-26T05_19_04_864Z-debug.log
```

and the log file is :

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\MB112830\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'cache',
1 verbose cli   'clear' ]
2 info using npm@5.7.1
3 info using node@v8.9.4
4 verbose config Skipping project config: C:\Users\MB112830/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
5 verbose stack Error: Cannot find module 'pump'
5 verbose stack     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
5 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
5 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
5 verbose stack     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
5 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MB112830\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\mississippi\index.js:1:85)
5 verbose stack     at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
5 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
5 verbose stack     at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
5 verbose stack     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
5 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
5 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
5 verbose stack     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
5 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\MB112830\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\cacache\lib\entry-index.js:10:12)
5 verbose stack     at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
5 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
5 verbose stack     at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
6 verbose cwd C:\Users\MB112830
7 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.10240
8 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\MB112830\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "cache" "clear"
9 verbose node v8.9.4
10 verbose npm  v5.7.1
11 error code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
12 error Cannot find module 'pump'
13 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

how to fix this?

Comment: have you tried just manually blowing away the cache and node_modules?

Comment: nope.. what should i do?

Comment: if you're worried about breaking something, you can always rename the folders - but yeah, give it a go

When you go to re-run `npm install` (or `yarn`) then it'll either work, or complain about `pump` which you can install as needed

Comment: I followed your steps and got issue fixed

Comment: glad to hear it!